# Group rows and sort each group

Tags: mysql, sorting, group-by

I have a mysql table for storing comments and subcomments with the schema:
`id`, `replyTo`, `text` where `replyTo` may be null, if the comment is not a sub-comment.

Currently I am doing the following query:

```
(select id as replyTo, text from Comments WHERE replyTo IS NULL) 
UNION 
(select  replyTo,text from Comments WHERE replyTo IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY replyTo;
```

Which gives me the comments in the order:

```
1. comment
2. subcomment
```

So if I have:

```
+----+---------+-----------+
| id | replyTo | text      |
+----+---------+-----------+
|  1 |    NULL | comment 1 |
|  2 |    NULL | comment 2 |
|  3 |       1 | sub 1     |
|  4 |       2 | sub 2     |
+----+---------+-----------+
```

This gives:

```
+---------+-----------+
| replyTo | text      |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 | comment 1 |
|       1 | sub 1     |
|       2 | comment 2 |
|       2 | sub 2     |
+---------+-----------+
```

My question is, how do I get them in the reversed order, that is, like this:

```
+-+------------+
|2|comment 2   |
|2|sub 2       |
|1|comment 1   |
|1|sub 1       |
+-+------------+
```

In other words, I would like to sort the elements by `replyTo ASC`, group them by `replyTo` (not as in mysql GROUP BY, which would remove all duplicate rows based on attribute), and then sort the groups by `replyTo DESC`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select replyTo, text from
(
select id as replyTo, text from Comments WHERE replyTo IS NULL 
UNION 
select  replyTo,text from Comments WHERE replyTo IS NOT NULL ORDER BY replyTo
)
order by replyTo DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SELECT COALESCE(replyTo,id) AS replyTo, text
FROM Comments
ORDER BY COALESCE(replyTo,id) DESC, id
```